# rendering a roleplaying map

Tags: orthographic

I would like to use blender to model a map of a castle, and then have a cutaway view of the map, with all the objects inside. Then, if possible, have the view almost orthographic.

Yes, I could just illustrate the map using photoshop or illustrator, but I wanted to see if I could use Blender in my pipeline.

How would you go about rendering in Ortho view from top down?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to go to top view

<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to go into orthographic

<kbd>RMB</kbd> on your camera

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

This will move your camera to your view

Now if you <kbd>F12</kbd>, you can render whatever your camera is looking at

Comment: The camera also has an [orthographic setting](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/types/camera/lens.html) if you want your render to be orthographic.